# Swiffy-converted Flash to HTML5 animated Google AdSense ads cause terrible performance jank in Chrome for Android

Tags: android, performance, google-chrome, ads, google-swiffy

I've been trying to figure out what's causing absolutely awful scrolling and general responsiveness performance issues in Chrome on our site lately, and my conclusion is that it's Swiffy that is powering some of Google's AdSense ads with animations. Recently, Google announced that they're now auto converting all Flash ads to HTML5, presumably with Swiffy, but it seems like their own browser takes a huge hit any time it sees them.

1. The animations themselves are very choppy. We're talking about 2fps.
2. The browser jank increases 1000%. I tried pausing the Chrome debugger attached to a mobile device via USB debugging and caught Swiffy code using touchstart and touchend, which are known for causing performance issues.
3. Any time a page loads without animated ads, the performance is fine.

We even tried to apply translateZ(0) to try to force ads to go to the GPU, but don't seem to have much success there.

Any ideas for optimizations that could force ad rendering on the GPU or help otherwise?

The website is http://www.androidpolice.com btw.

Cross-posted this to https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/chrome/report-a-problem-and-get-troubleshooting-help/android/Stable/WTm2NQVPz6k and https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/adsense/technical-errorsbugs/Hn0E2VsIdug.

Comment: I see a vote-to-close already and a downvote, but this is not a random code issue, it's a legitimate request for technical help with trying to optimize performance via a code change. There is very possibly a trick to move ads to the GPU, for example that I'm not aware of.

Comment: Caught the sonofabitch with dev tools and USB debugging open. Put some details of an example rogue ad here https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=467709.